Column lengths different between server and localhost
I have a PHP webapp running MySQL up on my Ubuntu server and it works fine, no errors. But when I mysqldump the database down to my local PC (Win10) and execute the sql (to get my local database exactly matching what's on the server), I always get errors like this:
Data too long for column 'FirstName'

Obviously the data isn't too long on the server, because the insert/update worked, and successfully stored the value into the FirstName column. The schema is identical between server and local. But on my local machine it believes that some value is too long.
I'm wondering if this has something to do with different collations between my server and my local dev box, but I don't know the right way to solve this.
I ran this on both server and localhost:
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_database';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation_database';

Result:
localhost character set: utf8mb4
server character set: utf8mb4
localhost collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
server collation: utf8mb4_general_ci

I added the following to my mysqldump script: -default-character-set=utf8mb4 and re-executed the dump download, then reran the dump. Same error.
I ran this on local and server:
SELECT @@version, @@sql_mode;

Results:
local @@version: 8.3.0
local @@sql_mode: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

server @@version: 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
server @@sql_mode: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Next I ran this against both local and server:
SHOW CREATE TABLE Users

Results:
(Both): DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Local SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%':

Server SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%':

Any ideas?

Post the relevant parts of the script you're using to get that error. Most likely you've got the column definition wrong.

Just set the column definitions to higher length values

Please run this query: SELECT @@version, @@sql_mode; on both the local and the server instance, and edit your post above to include the result.

Bill: done. Alegandro: column defs are fine, that's why it works on the server. Wofgang: that's how I've been solving it for years. It's clunky and time consuming and I'm tired of doing that. Thus the OP.

Why aren't you using the same version 8.0.35 locally? Or more to the point, why do you expect ten-year-old software works the same as current software?

The character_set_database is just the default character set, if you create given table with no specification for its character set. If you do specify, then the database's default character set is irrelevant. I think any mysqldump-based CREATE TABLE does specify the respective table's character set. You can SHOW CREATE TABLE on your local instance to confirm.

Bill, I have upgraded local MySQL to 8.3 and updated my OP. The upgrade changed nothing. Same error.

Bill, I ran SHOW CREATE TABLE and got the same result for both local and server. OP updated.

Pls show code, where this error issued.

ValNik, it's just a sql insert statement. The value of 1 column is too long is 1 database, but fits in another. The schema of both are identical.

There is some difference you are not seeing.  And we can't see it because you are holding back the full text of SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%' and other things on both servers.

Rick, I just posted SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%' in the OP, and I had already posted SHOW CREATE TABLE previously. Anything you want to see I will post.

I think I'd start by understanding specifically which row is causing the issue. Can you query for long values in your data, based on your schema for that table? E.g. if your column is a varchar 20:
SELECT FirstName FROM Users WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(name) > 18;

I'd also be curious if you created a new database on the server, if loading the dump in works or gives the same error?

In the working database, do a select order by char_length desc to find that value.

Could you please add also the mysqldump and Load Data commands you used?

Have you tried to export your active DB with Workbench? I noticed my self that the export function with Workbench is better. Another Idea would be to set-up a vm and import the DB there to see if the issue is your computer.
Besides this the error to me could be created due to the wrong length of 'firstname'. For example firstname varchar(10) and you store a firstname "FriskyAndFido" (More than 10 Char's). Could you please check your length for this attribute?

Kektuto: I don't use Workbench, I use HeidiSQL which is much better. mysqldump is the best way to get the backup, and it needs to be that way for automation purposes. As mentioned in the OP, the schema on the server and the schema on my local machine are identical. In fact, mysqldump drops and re-creates each table as part of the script, ensuring they're the same.

Based on your screenshots I can only see the Chartype and not the length issue. Could you mabe share the error msg and go into more detail?

Kektuto, the error message has always been in the OP, right at the top.
